# Android: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am getting "**android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout**" while i using "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" in my layout.

When my application goes to background and I open chrome, after that I press home button and open the application from recent. That time I am getting this error.

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

In gradle I have added below dependencies:

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
>
> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

This happens only when the google chrome opened. I tested by opening other app and then relaunching my app from recent. That time I'm not getting any crash.

Comment: try to remove support lib and clean project then add again.

Comment: and post your code .